# Unable to store instance in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm currently working on implementing a Stack in JavaScript using a LinkedList. However, I have an issue when instantiating a `Node` class. When I try to have a variable `let newNode = new Node(x)` I get `undefined`.

I'm not sure why that is but I would like to understand. If in the repl I run `new Node(x)` I get `{ val: -2, next: null }` a node. But when I store it in a variable I get undefined `let newNode = new Node(x)` it returns `undefined` if I console `newNode`.

```
/**
 * initialize your data structure here.
 */
var MinStack = function() {
  this.size = 0;
  this.min = null;
  this.first = null;
};

var Node = function(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.next = null;
}
/** 
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.push = function(x) {
  if(this.first == null) {
    this.first = new Node(x);
    this.min = this.first;
    this.size++;
    return
  }

  let newNode = new Node(x);
  if(newNode.val < this.min.val) {
    this.min = newNode.val;
  }
  let oldFirst = this.first;
  newNode.next = oldFirst;
  this.first = newNode;
  this.size++;
};
/**
 * @return {void}
 */
MinStack.prototype.pop = function() {
  if(this.first === null) {
    return;
  }
  if(this.min === this.first) {
    let current = this.first.next;
    this.min = current;
    while(current != null) {
      if(current.val < this.min.val || this.size === 2) {
        this.min = current;
      }
      current = current.next;
    }
  }
  this.first = this.first.next;
  this.size--;
  return
};
/**
 * @return {number}
 */
MinStack.prototype.top = function() {
  return this.first.val;
};
/**
 * @return {number}
 */
MinStack.prototype.getMin = function() {
    return this.min.val;
};
// ["MinStack","push","push","push","getMin","pop","top","getMin"]
// [[],[-2],[0],[-3],[],[],[],[]]

var obj = new MinStack()
obj.push(-2)
obj.push(0)
obj.push(-3)
console.log(obj.getMin())
obj.pop();
obj.top();
obj.getMin();
```

This is what I get when I get to the `debugger` breakpoint

```
> let newNode = new Node(x)
undefined
> newNode
undefined
> new Node(x)
{ val: 0, next: null }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What is the environment this code is executed in?

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt I'm using  `node -v
v14.0.0`

Comment: `node inspect leetcode-stack.js `

Comment: Can you share the entirety of the file? There's got to be something else going on here.

Comment: @djfdev I just edited the post with the fill file.

Answer (score 0):

"Node.js itself uses the repl module to provide its own interactive interface for executing JavaScript." https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_the_node_js_repl

According to the [Node REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options), by default, commands that get evaluated to undefined, print undefined on the console

You can ignore undefined when you use command like `let newNode = new Node(x)`. But the anomaly in your output is

```
> newNode
undefined
```

The above should not have happened

Ideally it should be

```
> x = 0
0
> let newNode = new Node(x)
undefined
> newNode
Node { val: 0, next: null }
> new Node(x)
Node { val: 0, next: null }
```

Comment: yes, I try a different node version but I still can't figure out what it is.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/submissions/ if you add the code to the submission it gets a timeout error

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in the following line

```
 if(newNode.val < this.min.val) {
    this.min = newNode.val;
  }
```

Here im suppose to pass the Node instead of the value

```
this.min = newNode.val;
```

So that when run `getMin` I access the node's value.

```
MinStack.prototype.getMin = function() {
    return this.min.val;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

missing semicolon after closing bracket of Node class/function definition

```
var Node = function(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.next = null;
}
```

should be

```
var Node = function(val) {
  this.val = val;
  this.next = null;
};
```